British sitcom at hospital, 3 men in ward + doctor, early 80s
I'm looking for a British sitcom from the early to mid 1980s, set in a hospital.  It had at least two - possibly three or more - series/seasons.  
It's about three men sharing a room/ward - and their doctor - whom they drive crazy (along with nurses and other staff).  Most is dialog between the characters, especially the three men.
In the opening-sequence, we see the main character (one of the three men) being rolled through the hospital corridors in a hospital-bed, while he sings: "I am H-A-P-P-Y, yes I'm H-A-P-P-Y, oh yes I am and sure I am, I am H-A-P-P-Y"...  Then a chorus of doctors, nurses and other patients joins in: "Oh yes he is and sure he is, he is H-A-P-P-Y" (or something along those lines).
In the final episodes, the three are finally discharged, and the doctor sadly thanks them for being wonderful patients and says they'll be sorely missed...  Until they've left the room and closed the door, and he starts dancing around of happiness -- which of course the three can see through a window to the corridor.
Does anybody remember what this show is called?

British sitcom Only When I Laugh which ran on ITV in 1979-1982.

A rather naive, middle-class man is admitted to a hospital ward and finds that he is sharing it with a working-class layabout and an upper-class hypochondriac. All three of them cause headaches for the hospital staff. 

Here's the intro with that H-A-P-P-Y song:




Oh yes, definitively it!  Thanks!

Richard Wilson? I don’t believe it!
